# An error occurs when attempting to create an S3 bucket and inject its policy simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently in the process of creating a Terraform script for an AWS S3 bucket intended for web hosting.

When I tried to create a bucket policy and s3 bucket at the same time, the "Access Denied" error occurred

But after first `apply`, I can put the policy into the bucket without any errors

So I thought maybe I missed some parameter like `depends_on`, but they don't have those parameter.

here is my script for s3 module.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "web_hosting_bucket" {
  bucket    =  var.domain_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "web_hosting_bucket_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.web_hosting_bucket.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "index.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "web_hosting_bucket_public_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.web_hosting_bucket.id
  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "web_hosting_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.web_hosting_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_policy_document" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  
  statement {
    sid       = "PublicReadGetObject" 
    effect    = "Allow"
    
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.domain_name}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `depends_on`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "web_hosting_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.web_hosting_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document.json

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.web_hosting_bucket_public_access]
}
```

Comment: oh.. I thought the depends_on is the parameter for specific resources... thank you